# Using orchard cms localization helper in an .aspx web form

Tags: orchardcms

According to orchard documentation [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Using-the-localization-helpers), the T() helper can be used in both Razor and ASPX View Engines.
I have add an aspx web form to my orchard module, but when I use T helper in it like this:

```
<%: T("This was a triumph!") %>
```

There is a compilation error by this message: `BC30451: 'T' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

How can I have localization in my .aspx web forms?

Answer (score 0):

Aspx support was dropped years ago, and webforms was never supported. You'll have to use Razor.